# facebook graph api returns blank data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm using the facebook sdk api, in a class to return a public facebook pages posts. But it returns blank, it doesn't throw an error.

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                 {
                     client_id = facebook_AppID, //App Id
                     client_secret = facebook_AppSecret, //App Secret
                     grant_type = "client_credentials" //client_credentials
                 });
var AccessToken = result.access_token;
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
JsonObject pagePost = facebookClient.Get("/thepagename/posts") as JsonObject;
string html = "";
foreach (var account in (JsonArray)pagePost["data"])
{
   html += (string)(((JsonObject)account)["message"]);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. blank for all the objects? 2. Did you validate your access token? 3. What do you mean by `thepagename`. Always, pls elaborate your question clearly so that users here could help you in one go!

Comment: pagePost returns Data [] no objects, The access token is valid. Thanks

Comment: Well, ok, i'll repeat myself- `3. What do you mean by thepagename`? Did you tried this in the Graph API Explorer? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Sry, "thepagename" is the id number of the facebook public name, yeah it works ok in the developer tool. Do I need to set permissions in the settings app?

Comment: try this `dynamic result = fb.Get("me?fields=id");` and tell me what `result` are you getting?

Comment: I get (OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user ?

Comment: If  your access token is really valid, use that as a parameter in your API call as- `?access_token=`. This will work